# Sequence of continuous functions in comple metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous complex functions on a (nonempty) complete metric space $X$, such that $f(x)=\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ exists for every $x\in X$.

a) Prove that there is an open set $V\neq\emptyset$ and a number $M<\infty$ such that $|f_n(x)|<M$ for all $x\in V$ and for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$

b) If $\epsilon>0$, prove that there is a open set $V\neq\emptyset$ and an integer $N$ such that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq \epsilon$ if $x\in V$ and $n\geq N$.

$\textbf{b)}$: For $N=1,2,3\ldots$, put

$$A_N=\{x:|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq \epsilon \ \ \mbox{if} \ \ m,n\geq N\}$$

then $X=\bigcup A_N $, by Baire's theorem there exists some $N$ such that $\overline{A_N}$ has a nonempty interior e.g. $\emptyset\neq V$ open and $V\subset \overline{A_N}$

Hence in $V$ we get

$$|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq \epsilon$$

for all $x\in V$ and $n\geq N$, because $f_m(x)\to x$ if $m\to \infty$.

Is correct b)?

Thank you, for any suggestion for a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument for (b) is correct. You can use the same idea for (a); this time let

$$A_N=\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|\le N\text{ for all }n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\;.$$

Comment: Thank you, Brian M. Scott.

Comment: @user126033: You’re welcome.

Comment: How to use the continuity of each $f_n$?.  $A_N=\overline{A_N}$ because each $f_n$ is continuous?

Comment: @user126033: I was a little sloppy: I should have written a non-strict inequality. I've fixed it; now $A_N$ is an intersection of closed sets, so it's closed.

Comment: The continuity of $f_n$ is relevant in  "$A_N$ is closed"?.

Comment: @user126033: Yes: $\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|\le N\}$ is closed, so its inverse image under any continuous function is closed. (I originally forgot that you were working with $\Bbb C$ rather than $\Bbb R$ and omitted the absolute value, which isn't needed in the real case.)

Comment: I thought so. Thak you, Brian M. Scott.

Comment: @user126033: You're welcome; my apologies for the original sloppiness.